Graceful labelling from permutations
There is a wolfram entry on obtaining graceful labellings from permutations.
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GracefulGraphFromPermutation/
I could not find an explanation of the method. I wonder whether anyone knows it. I tried decomposing a permutation in terms of $2$ cycles and looking using that to create a graph with edges corresponding to the cycles. However such a graph will not necessarily be graceful.
Is the construction quite easy or is it actually quite involved?

Can you please define what a graceful labelling is. Keep in mind this question/answer is not just for you but for anyone else in combinatorics who may be interested. Thanks!

Consider the example permutation $[2,3,6,5,8,1,7,4]$, one of the ones in the
Wolfram page linked. Convert this to its Lehmer
encoding, i.e., for each number
in turn count how many numbers to the right of it are less than it. This
gives $[1,1,3,2,3,0,1,0]$. This is called a labelling sequence in Ref.
1, where the algorithm is
given in the proof of thm 2.1. Label vertices from $0$ to $m$, where $m$ is
the degree of the permutation, here $8$. For the $i$th number in the Lehmer
encoding, $L_{i}$, draw an edge labelled $i$ from vertex  $L_{i}$ to vertex $
L_{i}+i\,.$ So for $i=1,$ edge 1 goes from vertex 1 to vertex 2; for $i=2,$
edge 2 goes from vertex 1 to vertex 3, etc.
1: D.A. Sheppard, The factorial representation of balanced labelled graphs,
Discrete Math., 15 (1976) 397.
